# Мониторинг таблицы mysql с помощью системы zabbix

Tags: zabbix

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые товарищи!

Есть Ubuntu 16.03, на ней mysql, база данных, и таблица, которую мне нужно поставить на мониторинг. А конкретно мне нужно знать количество селектов к этой таблице, и количество инсёртов/делитов из этой таблицы, допустим каждые 10-15 секунд. Помогите пожалуйста, уверен что можно это сделать, но как не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для инсёртов и делитов можно реализовать подсчёт через триггеры. Каждый триггер сохраняет статистику в какую-то таблицу, после через скрипт на сервере смотрит в неё и отправляет данные в zabbix.

Но на селект навесить триггер не получится. Смотрите вот такой ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/2786258/5707560 с помощью которого можно эмулировать работу триггера. В вашем случае там вместо добавления записи в таблицу должно быть обновление в таблице статистики.

---

Пример похуже: включить лог всех операций в MySQL и его парсить.

Comment: Триггеры я сделал, не могли бы вы поподробней рассказать про скрипт на сервере? И про наблюдение за селектами((

Триггер реагирует на инсерт и заносит в базу соответствующую строку, а что должно быть в скрипте на сервере? И как его запускать? 
Уточню свою задачу: когда количество инсертов и селектов к базе меньше порога, "загорается красная лампочка".

Comment: Заносить строку в таблицу не нужно. У вас при INSERT'e должен быть запуск подобного запроса: `UPDATE stats SET insert_counter = insert_counter + 1 WHERE table = "anytable"`. При удалении запрос должен быть подобного рода. Скрипт на сервере постоянно мониторит эту таблицу и при пересечении порога - отправляет данные в zabbix. Можете написать мне в Telegram : @smoliakov_there для подробной информации по вопросу.